# asp.net publish with whitespace removed

Tags: asp.net, optimization, compression

Obviously having whitespace in css, aspx and html pages is a great advantage at design time. But is there a way to (a tool that will) clear all the whitespace from all the files and possibly merge javascript and css files in a more optimal way.

I am using asp.net themes so there are quite a lot of separate css files that would be improved through some form of automated combining. I have seen a few http modules but that isn't quite what I want I just want to run something over the published project beofre sending it to the server.

EDIT: Compression at least in IIS is unfortunately not an option, we are currently running it on the same IIS server as a third party web based student management system. It doesn't like compression and the IIS options don't seem to be per application pool. I did apply asp.net compression but the bulk of my extra data seems to be the app_themes which I know would compress well I just don't want to have to manually go through compressing all the css separately.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[An empirical study on the effect of removing white space](http://nadeausoftware.com/articles/2007/03/don_t_use_html_white_space_removal_speed_web_site) from a not-untypical website (Drupal) showed minimal effects. (site also contains some links to non .net html white space removal tools)

I have gotten magical improvements in page size by aggressively managing viewstate size and using [Blowery's http compression](http://blowery.org/httpcompress/) module.

Another strategy is to do minifiation (merging many css files into one).   Telerik has such a component [RadStyleSheetManager](http://www.telerik.com/help/aspnet-ajax/radstylesheetmanager.html), it works only with style sheets embedded into assemblies.

Comment: not true with css in app_themes as there are multiple css sheets that should be compacted and possibly merged to reduce not just physical size but also the numbe rof separate http requests

Comment: What isn't true?  Anyhow, I did suggest RadStyleSheetManager which does what you recommended.

Comment: It might not significantly improve performance, but it can improve bandwidth consumption and cost.  For those who have bandwidth caps and a fair amount of traffic, the savings add up quickly.

Answer (score 2):

There is another way
http://omari-o.blogspot.com/2009/09/aspnet-white-space-cleaning-with-no.html

Answer (score 1):

I think one of the reasons that this was never included in .NET was because they expected you to turn on server compression in these scenarios.  IMO I don't agree with this -- I think it's a shame that at least aspnet_compiler.exe can't do this optimization.  It would be such a great performance boost on uncompressed connections.  Anyway, you can enable compression on IIS 6:

http://www.microsoft.com/technet/prodtechnol/WindowsServer2003/Library/IIS/d52ff289-94d3-4085-bc4e-24eb4f312e0e.mspx?mfr=true

And it's even easier and more flexible in IIS7 to do so.  I hope someone has a better solution than I!

Comment: Especially true when you don't have or it is difficult to get access to the web server to change the settings.

Answer (score 1):

[4 guys from Rolla](https://web.archive.org/web/20210510022033/https://aspnet.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120308-1.aspx) just published an article on a http module that removes white space.  You would need IIS 7 in integrated mode to make it work for css (or possibly IIS6 with wildcard mappings)

It looks more like a proof of concept, but the code is free.

Answer (score 0):

i found this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa719805(VS.71).aspx

greets!